# Invalid Spring @Query jpql translation to native sql when using embedded field

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, jpql

Given the following classe hierarchy, I am trying to query for CharacterDisposition that own a dependency on my Charakter object.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CHARACTER_DISPOSITION")
class CharacterDisposition{
    @OneToMany
    List<CharacterSlot> slots;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "CHARACTER_SLOT")
class CharacterSlot{
    @Embedded
    SceneCharacter sceneCharacter;
}

@Embeddable
class SceneCharacter{
    @ManyToOne
    Charakter character;
}
```

I am using the following jpql query within my spring repository interface,

```
@Query("SELECT cd "
        + "FROM CharacterDisposition cd "
        + "JOIN CharacterSlot cs "
        + "WHERE cs.sceneCharacter.character = :character")
List<CharacterDisposition> findCharacterDispositionWithCharacterDependency(Charakter character);
```

The above call produces the following native sql statement

```
select 
  characterd0_.id as id1_24_, characterd0_1_.scene_id as scene_id2_24_ 
from character_disposition characterd0_ 
    inner join character_slot characterd0_1_ on characterd0_.id=characterd0_1_.id 
    inner join character_slot characters1_ on where characters1_.character_id=?
```

Which is faulty because of an erroneous "on" keyword added before the final "where" statement.
I think this may have to do with my SceneCharacter being @Embedded.

I am using spring boot 2.2.1.RELEASE, hibernate and mysql 5 dialect.

Answer (score 0):

Try with the following -

```
@Query("SELECT cd "
        + "FROM CharacterDisposition cd "
        + "JOIN cd.slots cs "
        + "WHERE cs.character = :character")
```